# How to redirect a link using History to a page

Tags: reactjs

In my React app, I added `useHistory` to be able from my page Rovers to be redirect `onClick` of a button to one specific page. That button is contained inside 3 divs where onClick takes the name of the Rover and open the right page related to that Rover selected.

On that page, I would like to add 2 links which will redirect to the other 2 Rovers so the user no need to back to the Rovers page all the time.

My issue I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'roverName' of undefined
```

The code flow is as follow:

The rover button onClick is inside my Card component which shows the rover info and where I'm using History below

```
export default function CardComponent({
  name
  // other props
}) {   
  const history = useHistory();

  const redirectToRoverPage = () => {
    return history.push({
      pathname: `/mars-rovers/rover/${name}`,
      state: { roverName: name },
    });
  };

  return (
    <Col md={4} className="mb-5">
      <Card className="border-black mt-3">
          {/* some rover content here */}
          <Button variant="success" onClick={() => redirectToRoverPage()}>
            ENTER
          </Button>
        </Card.Body>
      </Card>
    </Col>
  );
}
```

Then inside my Rover page where I use 2 components

Index

```
export default function Rover(data) {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    Delayed.delay(() => {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }, 3000);
  });

  const roverName = `${data.location.state.roverName}`;
  return isLoading ? (
    <RoversLoader />
  ) : (
    <Container>
      <RoverIntro roverName={roverName} />
    </Container>
  );
}
```

RoverIntro

```
export default function RoverIntro({ roverName }) {
  return (
    <JumboTronWrapper>
      <Jumbotron className="jumbotron-intro">
        <div className="d-flex align-items-center">
          <h1>{roverName}</h1>
          <span className="ml-auto">
            <Link to="/mars-rovers">Rovers</Link>
            <Link to="/mars-rovers/rover/Curiosity">Curiosity</link> <-- Here clicking give me that error I showed above -->
            OTHER LINKS 
          </span>
        </div>
        <RoverText roverName={roverName} />
      </Jumbotron>
    </JumboTronWrapper>
  );
}
```

What I would like to understand as the first time I'm using History what should I do to permit the redirect from one Rover page to another rover page.

I want to avoid going back to mars-rovers main page all the time and allow a user to go directly to the other rover.

If you need it I can show more codes regarding this flow.

Comment: You don't need to wrap the handler in another function. Use just `onClick={redirectToRoverPage}`. And you could also use `useCallback` to memoize the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in your Card component, you navigate using history api and you specifically set state in the `push`.

```
  state: { roverName: name }
```

But then, in the Rover pages, you use `<Link/>` component without setting any state. This is why when you attempt to read `data.location.state.roverName` it throws.

I advice not to use the `history` api directly at all, but instead render a `<Link/>` in your Card.

And then within all your `<Link/>` components, specify the state inside `to={object}`, [docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link/to-object).

```
<Link
  to={{
    pathname: `/mars-rovers/rover/${name}`,
    state: { roverName: name },
  }}
/>
```

---

To answer your comment:

***Why make life difficult? JavaScript is beautiful powerful language without limits.***

```
export default function Links({ roverName: currentRover }) {
  const rovers = {
    curiosity: 'Curiosity',
    opportunity: 'Opportunity',
    spirit: 'Spirit',
  };

  return Object.keys(rovers).map(key => {
    if (rovers[key] === currentRover) return null

    const roverName = rovers[key]

    return (
      <Badge pill variant="primary" className="mr-2">
        <Link
          className="text-white"
          to={{
            pathname: `/mars-rovers/rover/${roverName}`,
            state: { roverName },
          }}>
          {roverName}
          </Link>
      </Badge>
    )

  })
}
```

Anyway, you should restructure your data a bit, you make adding new items in the future difficult. You should centralize your state and avoid duplication as is the case with your `rovers` definition in this `<Links/>` component. Instead, pass it via props and calculate the names from your original data like this:

```
const roverData = {
  curiosity: {
    name: 'Curiosity',
    landingDate: '',
    launchDate: '',
    maxDate: '',
    maxSol: '',
    status: '',
    totalPhotos: '',
  },
  opportunity: {
      name: 'Opportunity',
      // ...
    },
    spirit: { 
      name: 'Spirit',
      // ...
  },
};

const roverKeys = Object.keys(roverData)
const roverNames = roverKeys.map(key => roverData[key].name)
```

PS: It is better to pass a `key` of active rover to the link and in the `location.state` instead of its `name`. Keys are unique and also it allows you to manipulate objects directly without having to traverse the items and search for a particular value.

Comment: That is nice but I need an explanation because I need to add 2 links to the rovers and how I pass to that name the right rover name. 
example: https://pastebin.com/d8v48fX2
I have the 2 links on the same page and they have to redirect to the right rover so on the name how I make that to be correct

Comment: I tried in this way https://pastebin.com/x6uz7wSy but is ugly maybe can you help me make it better :)

Comment: thank you to teach me something I really appreciated,  I have a question about the second part i understood is better have it identified but do you believe I should make that change in this part of my code
https://github.com/Jakub41/Nasa-app/blob/curiosity-rover-page/src/Components/MarsRovers/RoversMain/index.js
And then use what you suggested to access the data better? If you have time maybe could you show me an example of what you mean just to discuss so I can learn it maybe a pastebin or we can discuss on another chat? I really would like to understand that approach you showed.

Comment: @Jakub I actually consider looking at your code in the following days. So stay tuned.

Comment: Hey if you would check on my code maybe we can chat on somewhere else like skype or FB where you prefer thanks

Comment: Let's continue somewhere else then [link](https://github.com/Jakub41/Nasa-app/pull/11)